# Executing TermQuery returns error 404

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

The following code fails the xml deserialization:

var query = new TermQuery();

var results = query.ExecuteQuery(context);

var r = results.Count();
Console.WriteLine(r);

I'm getting a 404 error. It looks like the resource for accessing SalesTerm queries is unavailable.

This is the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TermQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" />
```

and this is the response

```
<html><head><title>JBoss Web/2.1.12.GA-patch-03 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - Null subresource for path: https://services.intuit.com/sb/none/v2/556745565</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Null subresource for path: https://services.intuit.com/sb/none/v2/556745565</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource (Null subresource for path: https://services.intuit.com/sb/none/v2/556745565) is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/2.1.12.GA-patch-03</h3></body></html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the DevKit.  If you look at the endpoint, the DevKit is passing 'none' as the entity type.

https://services.intuit.com/sb/**none**/

As a workaround, you can use DevDefined or a similar library to construct your OAuth requests and call the service directly.  Here is an example:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dqTb7gFM